# banner image showing on all pages except forum and views result pages

Tags: theming

My image is showing on all pages except the forum and classifieds result pages.

How can I make sure it shows on all the pages?

In the block I have selected all pages and not checked any of diff types so that it should show site wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick inspection of your html shows that the block is showing up.  However, the issue is you have a relative path in your img src, eg, you have this:

```
<img src="sites/default/files/autumnleaves.jpg">
```

and that works fine when you are in the top level of your site.  But, when you go "down a level" it fails.  Changing it to:

```
<img src="/sites/default/files/autumnleaves.jpg">
```

should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like @jimajamma stated you are using a relative path which will be invalid when not in the top level of your site. I would recommend using an absolute path rather than a relative one, because then the url will still be valid even if your installation is in a subfolder of your webroot.

To generate an absolute url for your image you could use something like:

```
$url = url('sites/default/files/'.file_uri_target($uri), array('absolute'=>true));
```